# Getting a Module not found error when installing various packages

Tags: python, pip, package, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to import various modules, like nltk and pandas, using Jupyter notebook. While I have created a virtual environment and installed the packages (I received an all packages installed message on terminal), I keep getting that error on Jupyter notebook. Could I get help for this please? Thanks!(this is what the error looks like:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rwkqW.png)

Comment: Why not share with us the errors you have received and the commands you have tried in the order you tried them? The more specific you can be, the more someone may be able to help you.

Comment: We need more information are you using anaconda or are you not are you using pip3? Perhaps if you are try " sudo pip3 install pandas. "

Comment: Yes, it works! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

We need more information are you using anaconda or are you not are you using pip3? Perhaps if you are try " sudo pip3 install pandas. "